# Use attribute KEY and VALUE of a map inside a list element

Tags: terraform, hcl, hashicorp

I have defined a List called data, inside the list, i use a map with a key and a value. I now need to access the KEY and VALUE inside each element of the data list.

```
locals {
      data = [
        { "secret1" = 1 },
        { "secret2" = 1 },
        { "secret3" = 1 },
        { "secret4" = 1 },
        { "secret5" = 1 }
      ]
    }
```

The goal is to use the KEY and VALUE inside a google secret resource,
the value should then be used inside secret and version attribute.  Something like this:

```
data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "secret_datas" {
  count   = length(local.data)
  secret  = local.data[count.index].key
  project = "myproject"
  version = local.data[count.index].value
}
```

My Current Error Message

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on dependabot.tf line 38, in data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "secret_data":
│   38:   version = local.data[count.index].value
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is 1
│     │ local.data is tuple with 5 elements
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "value".
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: Hello, @Marcin I added my Error Code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be much easier with the modern [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) meta-argument. After optimizing the structure of the `data` in the `locals`:

```
locals {
  data = {
    "secret1" = 1,
    "secret2" = 1,
    "secret3" = 1,
    "secret4" = 1,
    "secret5" = 1
  }
}
```

we can easily use it in the resource.

```
data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "secret_datas" {
  for_each = local.data
  
  secret  = each.key
  project = "myproject"
  version = each.value
}
```